# Pytest raises exception but assert doesn't catch it, although they are the same type and same value

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

I am writing test for this function:

```py
def get_current_active_user(current_user: models.User = Depends(get_current_user)) -> models.User:
    if not current_user.is_active:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user
```

I am trying to check if the arguments of HTTPException are right. That is my test:

```py
def test_get_current_active_user_not_active():
    user: models.User = UserFactory()
    user.is_active = False

    with pytest.raises(HTTPException) as exc_info:
        get_current_active_user(current_user=user)
    
    assert exc_info.value == HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user')
```

For some reason, this assert is never true, although the values are the same. Debugging session:

```
>exc_info.value
HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user')

>type(exc_info.value)
<class 'fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException'>

>type(HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user'))
<class 'fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException'>

>exc_info.value == HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user')
False

>str(exc_info.value) == "HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user')"
False
```

Any ideas why this is happening are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your `assert` line execute?

Comment: Yes. It says that it is false, but everything matches.

Comment: Maybe it's because you're comparing two different HTTPException object instances, not their attributes. In this case, they are really different. I assume the HTTPException has a `value` attribute. Try: `exc_info.value == HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user').value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` in python might just compare the objects's ids, which is why the equality fails here.

Maybe you should try something like:

```py
assert exc_info.value.status_code == 400
assert exc_info.detail == 'Inactive user'
```

Answer (score 2):

As other pointed out, You can not use `==` sign with exception instances. Pytest provides [`match`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html) keyword in the raises function, you can use that if you want to match the string representation of the exception.

```
with pytest.raises(HTTPException, match=r"HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user')") as exc_info:
    get_current_active_user(current_user=user)
```

Comment: point 1. is incorrect and rest of answer is redundant

Comment: I changed the answer as there is already answers like this.

Comment: This will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Python exceptions do not compare equal:

```py
In [8]: from starlette.exceptions import HTTPException

In [9]: e1 = HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")

In [10]: e2 = HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")

In [11]: e1 == e2
Out[11]: False
```

it's not just Starlette:

```py
In [12]: e3 = ValueError("wtf")

In [13]: e4 = ValueError("wtf")

In [14]: e3 == e4
Out[14]: False
```

If you want to do a string comparison you will have to use `repr`:

```py
In [15]: str(e1)
Out[15]: ''

In [16]: repr(e1)
Out[16]: "HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Inactive user')"
```

But better would be to just compare the expected exception attrs (`pytest.raises` has already ensured it is of the expected type)

```py
assert exc_info.value.status_code == 400
assert exc_info.detail == 'Inactive user'
```

Comment: That is interesting. Any idea what is the other way to test it? exc_info.value.args is unfortunately empty, it returns "()"

Comment: yeah I think the underlying starlette error class is badly made by not calling `super` so the `args` gets set https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/exceptions.py#L8  I suggest instead do what @Mickael's answer suggested

Comment: yep, his answer works right. thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly compare here, try to use it with `assert`. This will work.

```py
assert exc_info.value.status_code == 400
assert exc_info.detail == "Inactive user"
```